# Unable to pass values back to HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I am using `EJS` to send some values to my page. Following is the code .

```
app.post('/ttt', function (req,res){
   res.render('index.ejs', {titles: 'CAME IN'})
});
```

HTML

```
<form id="mc-form" action="http://local_host:8081/ttt" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="email" value="" name="dEmail" class="email" id="mc-email" placeholder="type email &amp; hit enter" required=""> 
    <input type="submit" name="subscribe" >
    <label>REEEEE <%= titles %></label>
</form>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#mc-form").submit(function(e) {
    // e.preventDefault(); // Prevents the page from refreshing
    var $this = $(this); // `this` refers to the current form element
    $.post(
        $this.attr("action"), // Gets the URL to sent the post to
        $this.serialize(), // Serializes form data in standard format
        function(data) { /** code to handle response **/ 
            alert( data);
        },
        "json" // The format the response should be in
    );
});
```

However, after the user clicks on the submit button the text `CAME IN` is not getting displayed on the form. How can I sort this ?

Comment: you aren't appending the data(html) to the page

Comment: How can i do that. I am a beginner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return a json for the ajax not a view

node.js

```
app.post('/ttt', function (req,res){
   res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   res.send(JSON.stringify({titles: 'CAME IN'}));

});
```

plain.js

```
$("#mc-form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevents the page from refreshing
    var $this = $(this); // `this` refers to the current form element
    $.post(
        $this.attr("action"), // Gets the URL to sent the post to
        $this.serialize(), // Serializes form data in standard format
        function(data) { /** code to handle response **/
            $this.find('label').text(data.titles);//append the title to the form
        },
        "json" // The format the response should be in
    );
});
```

Comment: The label still doesn't get updated ? Am i missing the ID ? or else ?